# sed command for postgresql pg_hba.conf modification

Tags: sed, spacing

I want to edit content of pg_hba.conf using sed :

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
```

to

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
```

For know, I use this command that works:

```sh
sed -i 's/local   all             all                                     peer/local   all             all                                     trust/' pg_hba.conf
```

But I'm looking for a way to bypass all theses spaces

Comment: `sed -i 's/peer/trust/' pg_hba.conf`?

Comment: Perhaps `sed -Ei 's/^(local\s+all\s+all\s+)peer$/\1trust/' file` if using GNU sed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -E -i 's/local([[:space:]]+)all([[:space:]]+)all([[:space:]]+)peer/local\1all\2all\3trust/' test.conf
```

Or, since it seems like you have a GNU `sed`:

```sh
sed -E -i 's/local(\s+)all(\s+)all(\s+)peer/local\1all\2all\3trust/' test.conf
```

And certainly you can do [as potong did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69552913/sed-command-for-postgresql-pg-hba-conf-modification/69552977#comment122938517_69552913) in the comments and reduce this to

```sh
sed -E -i 's/(local\s+all\s+all\s+)peer/\1trust/' test.conf
```

Note:

- `-E` enables the POSIX ERE syntax (no need to escape `+` and `(...)`)
- `([[:space:]]+)` / `(\s+)` defines capturing groups with IDs starting with 1 that match one or more whitespaces
- `\1`, `\2` and `\3` are placeholders, backreferences to the appropriate group values.

In `s/(local\s+all\s+all\s+)peer/\1trust/`, you capture the whole part before `peer` and match `peer`, then the whole match is replaced with the part before `peer` (with `\1`) + `trust`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this `sed` if the string that needs to be changed is not always going to be `peer`

```
$ sed -i 's/\S*$/trust/' input_file
# local is for Unix domain socket connections trust
local   all             all                                     trust
```

Comment: Your answer works but I have many other lines containing ```peer``` and ```trust``` that I want to keep